# Unable to perform remote debugging with IDA Pro in WSL

Tags: ida

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 under Windows Subsystem Linux 2 and I want to perform some remote debugging with IDA Pro.

As with other VMs I have used, I can perform remote debugging when send the executable `linux_server` and `linux_server64` to the VM and execute them. However, in WSL instance, when I run the server and use correct port and IP, there is still connection from IDA Pro to the VM, however, I kept receive this error:

In WSL instance:

```
IDA Linux 64-bit remote debug server(ST) v7.7.27. Hex-Rays (c) 2004-2022
Listening on 0.0.0.0:23946...
2023-03-01 09:49:40 [1] Accepting connection from 172.19.208.1...
Warning: rpc: bad packet length
2023-03-01 09:49:40 [1] [1] Could not establish the connection
2023-03-01 09:49:40 [1] Closing connection from 172.19.208.1...
```

In host machine:
[image]

I am pretty sure that information in setting is true (IP, port, etc.) I have tried to config by allowing port 23946 at WSL instance but it does not work either.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know it is the issue or not, but when I change to Remote Debugging with Linux Debugger rather than GDB, I could do it well. I do not know sure but I also install [Pwndbg](https://github.com/pwndbg/pwndbg) along GDB, maybe it could be the issue.